# PHP preg_replace on null string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to insert a string of character or insert a word where $string value = Null; using PHP's preg_replace.
I couldn't find a proper regexp which will match null string.

my code is like this:

```
$string ={member_repeat_designation___designation};
$pattern ='//' ;
$replacement = 'Member';
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Ok I am submitting the full code here why I need it.

```
$string1= "Ln. {member___first_name} {member___last_name<br>
{member_repeat_designation___designation}";
$string2="{member_repeat_designation___designation}";

$patterns=array();
$patterns[0]= '/President/';
$patterns[1]= '/Team Leader/';

$replacements=array();
$replacements[0]= '{member_repeat_designation___designation} {member___club_name}';
$replacements[1]= 'TL';

$patt=0;
$rep='Member';

$a=preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string1);
$b=preg_replace($patt, $rep, $string2);
return $a <br> $b;
```

Comment: I don't get it if the string is null then you don't need to replace anything, just check if it's null and if it is then set it to whatever value you like?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate NULL char or invalid UTF-8 sequence?

Comment: It is not always null. {member_repeat_designation___designation} can derive value including null. I want replace the empty values with the word "Member"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need regex for this? PHP has an in-built function for this purpose:

```
$string = '{member_repeat_designation___designation}';
if( is_null($string) ) {

//string is null, do whatever

}
if( trim($string) == ''  ) {

//string is empty

}
```

Documentation: [**`is_null()`**](http://php.net/is_null)

Comment: Or use `$string === NULL`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match NULL char,

```
return preg_replace('/\\0/', $replacement, $string);
```

However...

```
Empty value : ""
Null char   : "\0"
```

They are **entirely different**.